# How can I paginate Laravel's Eloquent's relationships' relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, collections, pagination, relationship

I have two tables, `users` and `profiles`. A user has one profile. Also a user has referrals. The referrals are referenced by the column referrer_id in the users' table. So a user has a referrer, and a user can have many referrals.

Define a one-to-one relationship on the User's Model:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

Define an inverse one-to-one relationship on the User's Model:

```
public function referrer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Define a one-to-many relationship on the User's Model:

```
public function referrals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'referrer_id');
}
```

Define an inverse one-to-one or many relationship on the Profile's Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I wish to retrieve the user's profile, the user's referrals along with their profiles, and the referrals' referrals along with a count of each of the referrals' referrals.

The following Eloquent query works, but doesn't paginate:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ReferralsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user()->loadMissing(['profile', 'referrals' => function ($query) {
            $query->with(['profile', 'referrals'])->withCount('referrals');
        }]);
    }
}
```

I've tried to add `->paginate()` to the query (on both as show below and also one or the other) but it doesn't work:

```
return $request->user()->loadMissing(['profile', 'referrals' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['profile', 'referrals'])->withCount('referrals')->paginate(2);
}])->paginate(2);
```

Adding it to the inner function doesn't do anything, and adding it to the main query just retrieves the entire `users` table.

**EDIT**
I've realized that adding `->paginate()` to the inner function actually does limit the number of rows in the collection, but there is no Paginator instance anywhere, so I don't have access to any of the links to move pages.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by doing it separately:

```
$profile = $request->user()->profile()
    ->firstOrFail();

$referralsPaginator = $request->user()->referrals()
    ->with('profile')
    ->withCount('referrals')
    ->paginate(2);
```